# Solving time dependent Schrodinger equation for a wavefunction and harmonic oscillator

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, physics, modeling

How can I obtain a GIF/graph similar to these ones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#/media/File:StationaryStatesAnimation.gif) by solving the time-dependent Schrodinger equation

$$ i\hbar\frac{\partial ψ(x,t)}{\partial t} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2ψ(x,t) + V(x)ψ(x,t)$$

where the wavefunction is

$$ψ(x,t)=Ae^{i(kx-ωt)}$$

Comment: Do you mean, you want to obtain GIF similar to the one in the link by solving Schrodinger equation, but you don't know where to start?

Comment: @xzczd yes, that is what I meant. Sorry for not phrasing it properly

Comment: The plane wave ψ you wrote is not a solution to the S.E. when V = 1/2 ω^2 x^2.

Comment: In other words, the GIF can not be obtained (in an easy manner, at least) by setting $ψ(x,t)$ to $Ae^{i(kx-ωt)}$.

Comment: Actually the _Mathematica_ code for the GIF is available here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:StationaryStatesAnimation.gif

Comment: Wow, I did not look at that code when I produced my answer but it is REMARKABLY similar.  Mostly I didn't make my figures look as nice, and I didn't use a frame-based approach but an `Animate` approach.  Otherwise, basically the same!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In units where hbar, m, and omega_0 are set to 1, the Schrödinger equation for the [quantum harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) can be written

$$
  i \partial_t \Psi(x,t) = \left(- \frac{1}{2} \partial_x^2 + \frac{1}{2} x^2\right)\Psi(x,t)
$$

and the time-dependent solutions can be written as a sum of time-dependent complex exponentials times the time-independent eigenfunctions,

$$
 \Psi(x,t) = \sum_n c_n \Psi_n(x,t)
$$
with
$$
 \Psi_n(x,t) =  e^{i E_n t} \psi_n(x)
$$

where the eigenenergies $E_n = n + 1/2$ and the energy eigenfunctions

$$
\psi_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n n!}} \pi^{-1/4} \exp(-x^2/2) H_n
$$

where $H_n$ are the `HermiteH` polynomials.

So,

```
\[Psi][n_][x_] = 1/Sqrt[2^n n!] \[Pi]^(-1/4) Exp[-(x^2/2)] HermiteH[n, x]
Energy[n_] := n + 1/2
\[CapitalPsi][n_][x_, t_] = Exp[I Energy[n] t] \[Psi][n][x]
```

Now we just need to plot,

```
figure = Animate[
 GraphicsGrid[
  {{Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@\[CapitalPsi][0][x, t], {x, -4, 4}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 1}],
    Plot[Abs[\[CapitalPsi][0][x, t]]^2, {x, -4, 4}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
    },
   {Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@\[CapitalPsi][1][x, t], {x, -4, 4}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 1}],
    Plot[Abs[\[CapitalPsi][1][x, t]]^2, {x, -4, 4}, 
     PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
    }
   }],
 {t, 0, 4 \[Pi]},
 ]
```

Then we can export to GIF

```
Export["figure.gif", figure]
```

I can't get the GIF to loop "around and around" in time; instead it goes back and forth.  Hopefully you'll consider this a minor detail.  This is the result (the left panels are the real and imaginary parts of $\Psi_n(x,t)$ for n=0 and 1, the right panels are $|\Psi_n|^2$ which is time-independent):

[image: first two eigenstates]

To get the non-stationary behavior of the last row of your example we need to take a linear superposition of more than one $\Psi_n(x,t)$.  Below I take a simple linear combination, $1/sqrt(2)$ of the 0th and 1st eigenstates,

```
nonstationary[x_, t_] = 
  1/Sqrt[2] (\[CapitalPsi][0][x, t] + \[CapitalPsi][1][x, t]);

figure2 = Animate[
  GraphicsGrid[
   {{Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@nonstationary[x, t], {x, -4, 4}, 
      PlotRange -> {-1, 1}],
     Plot[Abs[nonstationary[x, t]]^2, {x, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}]
     }}],
  {t, 0, 4 \[Pi]},
  AnimationDirection -> Forward,
  AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity
  ]
```

Then

```
Export["figure2.gif", figure2]
```

yields

[image: nonstationary example]

(same caveat with respect to time not looping properly).

You can combine the different `Animate[GraphicsGrid[...`s to make one figure, if you want to combine the stationary and nonstationary figures.

Comment: Not sure why the latter GIF isn't animating on this page; if you click through it IS animated!

Comment: If you have a different potential you won't be able to use these specific $\psi_n$s and $E_n$s (as they depend on the potential).  However, if you can solve the time-independent problem you can reuse the framework here.

Comment: To get the GIF to loop infinitely you need to say `"AnimationRepetitions"->Infinity` in the `Export` call. To get it to export without controls you can also set `Controls->None` I believe or a similar option. That will _just_ export the image itself as a GIF.

Comment: I tried that following an answer I found to a question here to no avail.

Comment: It's dumb but you need `"AnimationRepetitions"` as a string. In 12.1 this works for me: ```Export["~/Desktop/woof.gif", 
 Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[2 x + \[Phi]], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {-1, 1}}], 
  {\[Phi], 0, 1.06 \[Pi]},
  AnimationDirection -> Forward
  ],
 "ControlAppearance" -> None,
 "AnimationRepetitions" -> Infinity,
 FrameRate -> 5
 ]``` except it doesn't respect that `AnimationDirection` for some dumb reason. The `"AnimationRepetitions"` as a string has worked since at least 10.4 in my experience